# Courier Build for - Umbraco v6.2.4

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6, umbraco-blog, umbraco-contour

I have just finished an umbraco project and want to install Courier.

How ever I am a bit confused about which version of Courier I should Install.

I am using Umbraco v6.2.4 (Assembly version: 1.0.5394.15649)

But on the Courier package page > http://our.umbraco.org/projects/umbraco-pro/umbraco-courier-2

This is what I can see under the compatibility.

7.1.x (0%)

7.0.x (0%)

6.2.x (0%)

6.1.x (100%)

6.0.x (untested)

4.11.x (100%)

4.10.0 (untested)

4.9.1 (untested)

4.9.0 (100%)

Does this mean that it will not work at all with the LATEST VERSION of umbraco? If so How can I change my v6.2.4 umbraco down to 6.1.x (I used nuget to install it)

I have already finished my umbraco project, content done etc... I really don't want to have to start again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/COU-62), it appears to work in Umbraco 6.2.x

This would correspond to build Courier_2.7.8.42.v6.zip onwards, at the [nightly Courier downloads here](http://nightly.umbraco.org/UmbracoCourier/2.7.8/nightly%20builds/)

Comment: Ok So If i download  Courier_2.7.8.42.v6.zip from the Nightly, I should be ok?

Comment: I think so yes, although it would probably be best to get the latest version 2.7.8.43, rather than 2.7.8.42.